# How to make recursive sorted list function work?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to make a list sorting algorithm, without using Python's sorted. I have this so far:

```
def order(lst):
    if lst == [] or len(lst) == 1:
        return lst
    elif lst[0] < order(lst[1:])[0] or lst[0] == order(lst[1:])[0]:
        return [lst[0]] + order(lst[1:])
    return order(lst[1:]) + [lst[0]]
```

However, it has trouble dealing with lists with repeated entries. I'm assuming that this is because the program that you can keep expanding the list based on whether something is greater or less, and if it runs in to something that has an equal value same, it breaks the process. However, I'm not sure how to fix it at all, so is there a better way to do this or do I have to use a different way (using min is my best bet at this point)? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: There are various sorting algorithms....which of them are you trying to implement?

Comment: Use `<=` instead of (`<` or `==`).

Comment: I'm trying to implement a function that sorts the numbers in order from least to greatest.

Comment: @WalR That is a much better way to write the code cleaner, but it still gives me incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

```
def order(lst):
    count = 0 #this is the count of how many times we've seen a repeated digit
    def helper(lst):
        nonlocal count
        if len(lst) <= 1:
            return lst
        lst_without_min = []
        for x in lst:
            if count < 1 and x == min(lst): #okay, we've already seen the minimum digit once, if it's repeated again keep it in there
                count += 1
            else:
                lst_without_min.append(x)
        return [min(lst)] + order(lst_without_min)
    return helper(lst)
```

Here's a working solution that is really long and probably inefficient, but it works.